# How to map result from Scalardb get into model

Tags: java

Question 1

Following the example at https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md, the result of Get could be retrieved as

```
int current = ((IntValue) result.get().getValue(BALANCE).get()).get();
```

What happens if BALANCE isn't present. Is there a `getOrElse` like API which could be used?

Question 2

The way IntValue is retrieved is different from TextValue. TextValue seems to have an additional getString call. What does the getString call do?

```
val resultGetEmail = resultGet.getValue("email").get.asInstanceOf[TextValue].getString.get()
val resultGetBucket = resultGet.getValue("bucket").get.asInstanceOf[IntValue].get
```

Question 3

TextValue also seem to have `elseOrGet`, `elseOrThrow` or `orElseGet`. Where are these defined? I couldn't find them in the javadocs.

Question 4
Why IntValue hasn't got any `orElse` options?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are more like questions for Java's `Optional`, not about Scalar DB. So, please take a look at this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I don't know Java so wasn't sure about Optional. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.